# Using logical Operator 'or' return always true

Tags: php, debugging, logical-operators

hei, so what i am trying to do here is to verify two sources of my function if is set $this->post["search"] use it or if is set $this->post["id"] use id, but not both:

```
($this->post["search"] or $this->post["id"])
```

If i dump i get a bool value with true answer, why?
So if i have a long string like a sql string i don't want to use `elseif`'s i want to be more like:

```
$this->sql->cell("select search_for('" . $this->post["search"] or $this->post["id"] . "') as response;");
```

Comment: ($this->post["search"] or $this->post["id"]) returns _true_ or _false_ rather than the contents of the post array elements.i.e. if $this->post["search"]  contains 'find me' then it is _true_.

Comment: i wanted to use in one line like in the question, but seems like i need to use if/else

Comment: _($this->post["search"]? $this->post["search"] : $this->post["id"])_ will return either value if at least one is supplied.  [Using the PHP Ternary Operator](http://www.sitepoint.com/using-the-ternary-operator/)

Answer (score 0):

You probably should pass the control flow depending on what’s set:

```
if ( isset($this->post["search"]) ) {
  // deal with search
} else if ( isset($this->post["id"]) ) {
  // deal with id
} else { 
  // gracefully reject dealing: nothing to do
}
```

BTW, `isset` returns `true` for empty strings:

```
$test = array( 'a' => '' );
var_dump(isset($test['a']));
//⇒ bool(true)
```

To determine whether `$_POST` parameter has a value, use:

```
!empty($_POST['id'])
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: i modify my question, please! so i don't want to use elseif's i want to know why if i dump the line $this->post["search"] or $this->post["id"] i get always true?